# Remove duplicate only if same content within a column for each groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe such as :

```
Groups Subgroups Species Anothercolum
G1     1         SP1     jkl
G1     1         SP2     ds
G1     2         SP1     9DS
G1     2         SP2     JD
G1     3         SP1     Js2_0
G1     3         SP2     KUIO
G2     1         SP4     JUI
G2     1         SP5     NA
G2     1         SP6     NA
G2     2         SP4     900
G2     2         SP5     LO
G2     2         SP7     dez
G2     3         SP4     dez
G2     3         SP5     ge
G2     3         SP7     gez
```

And I would like to remove duplicate elements within `Groups` and `Subgroups` but only when there is the same content of `Species`.

For instance, for `G1`:

```
Groups Subgroups Species
G1     1         SP1
G1     1         SP2
G1     2         SP1
G1     2         SP2
G1     3         SP1
G1     3         SP2
```

I keep the first `Subgroups1` since **SP1** and **SP2** are both in `Subgroup1` and `Subgroup2`;

```
Groups Subgroups Species
G1     1         SP1
G1     1         SP2
```

But for **G2** :

```
Groups Subgroups Species
    G2     1         SP4
    G2     1         SP5
    G2     1         SP6
    G2     2         SP4
    G2     2         SP5
    G2     2         SP7
    G2     3         SP4
    G2     3         SP5
    G2     3         SP7
```

The `Subgroup1` does not have the same 3 species as `subgroup2` and `3`, so I keep that one, but remove the `subgroup3` and keep `subgroup2` since they have the same species.

I should then get the following expected output  :

```
Groups Subgroups Species Anothercolum
G1     1         SP1     jkl
G1     1         SP2     ds
G2     1         SP4     JUI
G2     1         SP5     NA
G2     1         SP6     NA
G2     2         SP4     900
G2     2         SP5     LO
G2     2         SP7     dez
```

Here is the dataframe if it can help:

```
structure(list(Groups = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", 
"G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2"), Subgroups = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Species = c("SP1", 
"SP2", "SP1", "SP2", "SP1", "SP2", "SP4", "SP5", "SP6", "SP4", 
"SP5", "SP7", "SP4", "SP5", "SP7")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: You removed nothing in G2 as far as I can tell. This does not match your description.  May you please clarify?

Comment: Oups you are right, I removed the wrong one, it  is subgroup3 that should be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` to find duplicates even for a list. Something like this

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Groups, Subgroups) %>% 
  summarize(across(c(Species, Anothercolum), list), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(Species)) %>% 
  unnest(c(Species, Anothercolum))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  Groups Subgroups Species Anothercolum
  <chr>      <int> <chr>   <chr>       
1 G1             1 SP1     jkl         
2 G1             1 SP2     ds          
3 G2             1 SP4     JUI         
4 G2             1 SP5     NA          
5 G2             1 SP6     NA          
6 G2             2 SP4     900         
7 G2             2 SP5     LO          
8 G2             2 SP7     dez
```

---

Another (more efficient) version using `paste0` instead of `list` since you can find this warning from `?duplicated`

> Warning
> Using this for lists is potentially slow, especially if the
> elements are not atomic vectors (see vector) or differ only in their
> attributes. In the worst case it is O(n^2).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Groups, Subgroups) %>% 
  summarize(across(c(Species, Anothercolum), paste0, collapse = ","), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(Species)) %>%
  separate_rows(Species, Anothercolum, sep = ",", convert = TRUE)
```

For this one, you will have to be careful about the separator used. However, both should be fine if you do not have a large dataset.

Comment: nice answer with `summarize` and `unnest`, upvoted!

Comment: Thank you! I also like yours. It's always good to see a base R solution @ThomasIsCoding.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your help it is a nice code :-) but what if I have several other columns I want to keep in the ouptut (I added in the example)

Comment: Hi @clippycentra, I have updated the code. See `?across` for more details.

Comment: thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 3):

A base R option

```
merge(
  df,
  subset(
    aggregate(
      Species ~ .,
      df,
      c
    ),
    as.logical(ave(Species, Groups, FUN = Negate(duplicated))),
    select = c(Groups, Subgroups)
  )
)
```

gives

```
  Groups Subgroups Species
1     G1         1     SP1
2     G1         1     SP2
3     G2         1     SP5
4     G2         1     SP4
5     G2         1     SP6
6     G2         2     SP7
7     G2         2     SP4
8     G2         2     SP5
```